# .NET control to edit xml file

Tags: .net, xml, designer

Can anyone reccomend a .net control (winforms) that can be used to as a designer to edit xml files / DSL files ??

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to create a series of objects that [serialize](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316730) into your desired XML structure.

Then you can deserialize your XML into objects and then bind them to a [PropertyGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.aspx)

Comment: Good luck, hopefully whoever makes something like that doesn't charge like a wounded bull. Just be aware that you can provide your own custom editors for the propertyGrid control.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you got your answer,
There are a couple of 3rd party controls availbale [QWhale](http://www.qwhale.net/) and [ActiPro](http://www.actiprosoftware.com/)

hope this helps.